# How do I remove whitespace but maintain column structure?

Tags: sed, whitespace

I am trying to take several rows of data that look like this:

```
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f                MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1  4488163       0  14.7gb   7.4gb
green open  foundational-cm-add-salesforce-customer-number-c            GA3dXwz3Rn2_EmZGV1oEfg 32 1   219696       0     1gb 520.3mb
      close foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg                           g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ                                      
green open  foundational-cm-dw-customer-dim-hist-filtered               koNU-arFQHSFOEkmj_xc9w 32 1   141210       0 887.1mb   450mb
green open  datasync-dm-customer-vw-coalesce-a                          rvEuYU4NQ0SS69qB3UGLCA 32 1  2656210       0  11.6gb   5.8gb
```

And use this sed command to remove extra whitespace: sed 's/\s+/ /g'

The issue is that in doing this I get the following:

```
green open foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1 4488163 0 14.7gb 7.4gb
green open foundational-bus-layer-comm-instrument-customer-f WF0wR4O3RxOZ2bzwm_yGRw 32 1 842214 0 1.5gb 808mb
 close foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ 
green open foundational-cm-add-salesforce-customer-number-c GA3dXwz3Rn2_EmZGV1oEfg 32 1 219696 0 1gb 520.3mb
green open foundational-cm-dw-customer-dim-hist-filtered koNU-arFQHSFOEkmj_xc9w 32 1 141210 0 887.1mb 450mb
```

What I would like is something that looks like this:

```
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1 4488163 0 14.7gb 7.4gb
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-instrument-customer-f WF0wR4O3RxOZ2bzwm_yGRw 32 1 842214 0 1.5gb 808mb
      close foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ 
green open  foundational-cm-add-salesforce-customer-number-c GA3dXwz3Rn2_EmZGV1oEfg 32 1 219696 0 1gb 520.3mb
green open  foundational-cm-dw-customer-dim-hist-filtered koNU-arFQHSFOEkmj_xc9w 32 1 141210 0 887.1mb 450mb
```

So I would like to maintain the column structure while also removing the extra whitespace.

Any ideas??

**********EDIT************
I tried the suggestion below, and got the following:

```
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-contract-line-item-f 3987969 6.2gb
green open  foundational-idea-dlvry-lot-vldtd 0 4.2kb
green open  .trek-new 0 1.2kb
green open  add-pabbto-idaqowner-idaq-customerinformation-v9c2 948 3.4mb
 close      add-pabbto-idaowner-results-cc-v26 
green open  sym-tib-add-openorder-detail 261763 399.7mb
green open  idn 10417 8.2mb
green open  sym-adc-outboundinvoice-c 43012 46mb
```

So.. close? But the "close" still needs to move over...

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps try with this gnu sed

```
sed 's/  */ /3g;s/  */'$'\1''/2' infile | column -s $'\1' -t
```

**Explain :**

---

```
s/  */ /3g
```

replace 1 or more whitespace by only one from the third occurence to the end.
The start of the line is never change.

So the first line

```
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f                MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1  4488163       0  14.7gb   7.4gb
```

became

```
green open  foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1 4488163 0 14.7gb 7.4gb
```

The change start after -f

The problematic line

```
      close foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg                           g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ
```

became

```
      close foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ
```

The change start after -stg

---

s/  */'$'\1''/2

replace 1 or more whitespace by the char Hex01 on the second occurence.

So the first line became

```
green openHex01foundational-bus-layer-comm-ticket-details-f MqWrI9I6Q7enZnLjH9xZHw 32 1 4488163 0 14.7gb 7.4gb
```

The problematic line became

```
      closeHex01foundational-sls-dtl-bpcs-otc-stg g2xS6fDRR0OW_W_24UjuYQ
```

---

```
column -s $'\1' -t
```

format the output in 2 col with the separator Hex01

---

If there are not whitespace but tab, you can use

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/ /3g;s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/'$'\1''/2' infile | column -s $'\1' -t
```

Comment: I tried your first command above, and put the output in my EDIT above. Also, if you could explain what the first command does, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I can't explain what you get. I update the answer for details.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! That helps tremendously. Here is the working solution:

Comment: curl -ku tresata:admin https://172.17.2.196:9200/_cat/indices | sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f1-3,7,9 | sed 's/  */'$'\1''/2' | sed 's/  */'$'\1''/1' | column -s $'\1' -t